# Continuous Sign in dialog box in for Sandbox testing

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, ios11, storekit

I'm trying to test my in-app purchases and when I go to buy it I get the sign in box over and over again. Her is my Helper

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class IAPHelper: NSObject {
    private final let productIdentifiers: Set<String> = ["non-consumable"]
    static let sharedIntance = IAPHelper()

    private var request: SKProductsRequest!
    private var products: [SKProduct] = []

    func performProductRequestForIdentifiers() {
        request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }

    func setupPurchases(_ handler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            handler(true)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            return
        }
        handler(false)
    }

    func createPaymentRequestForProduct() {
        guard let product = products.first else { return }
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        let payment = SKMutablePayment(product: product)
        payment.quantity = 1
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }
}

extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        products = response.products
    }
}

extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                print("purchasing")
                break
            case .purchased:
                print("purchased")
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .failed:
                print("failed")
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .restored:
                print("restored")
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .deferred:
                print("deferred")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the App-Delegate, I check for the ability to make purchases and start an observer

```
IAPHelper.sharedIntance.setupPurchases { (success) in
    if success {
        IAPHelper.sharedIntance.performProductRequestForIdentifiers()                
    }
}
```

And in my main `ViewControoller` in a `UIButton` I call `IAPHelper.sharedIntance.createPaymentRequestForProduct()`

I have my sandbox user made in connect and the in-app purchase made in connect also.  I'm signed out of my real account on my iPhone and signed in with the sandbox.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has something wrong, specifically in the part where you are adding the SKPaymentTransactionObserver.

Your below function is a little bit weird:

```
func setupPurchases(_ handler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            handler(true)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            return
        }
        handler(false)
    }
```

What i suggest you to do is the following:

```
func setupPurchases() {
         SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
}
```

and then add the below code to the AppDelegate class, inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
IAPHelper.sharedIntance.setupPurchases()
```

Hopefully this will solve the issue.